# Unable to use the content='' to add :after inside the link tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tags

There is a CSS unline effect for the `::after` element when it is hovered.
Here is an example:

```
.wrapper a:hover:after, footer.main-footer a:hover:after {
   background:#ff0000;
}
```

Here is the test link:
http://www.epicdesign.com.hk/portfolio/north-district-flower-bird-insect-and-fish-show-2014/

In the Chrome developer console, notice that at the top corner there is some link tag has `::after` inside, that will show the effect

```
<a href="test.com" data-term="event">Event::after</a>
```

[image]

At the bottom corner, some link does not have it, although in the console you can notice that it already have `content=''`-attribute.

```
<a class="back-to-portfolio" href="test2.com">All</a>
```

[image]

The problem is, why doesn't the bottom links contain `:after` as I have used `content=''`? How to fix it?
Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: I think the `width` is a problem. There is a `width: 100%` in the first screenshot, do you see the same for the second also?

Comment: the width : 100% means the underline width goes to 100, however, even I hardcode the 100% it does not show at bottom links, as it does not have :after at the link tag

Comment: You've got a `display: none!important` for the `:after` element in your kalium.css. If this setting is removed you'd notice that it works properly.

Comment: yes , you are right, don't notice the theme have such CSS, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I am not posting an answer because the question would most likely get closed (and deleted) as code to reproduce the problem is in an external site.